# Myfaces, facesContext.messageList always empty unless it's parent has a rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I want to create a simple register form with JSF2 ajax and Bean Validation, which allows to display all error messages with custom format in the `ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList}" var="m"` area when the validation fails. My code works well with Mojarra, but when I switch  to Myfaces2.1, the messages never show with `ui:repeat` -- it only leaves an empty `ol`tag there, and the `facesContext.messageList`  seems to be empty. It still works with `h:messages` but that's not what I want.
However, today I found a wierd workaround: Adding the attribute `rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"` to one of the `ui:repeat`'s parent component.
I can't understand why this `rendered="..."` matters because the errorDisplay component did get re-rendered everytime. Does this test `#{not empty facesContext.messageList}` change anything ?

```
<h:form>
Name:<h:inputText value="#{hello.name}" id="name"/>
<br/>
Age :<h:inputText value="#{hello.age}" id="age" converterMessage="'Age'必须是一个数字"/>

<h:commandLink value="register" type="submit">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="errorDisplay"/>
</h:commandLink>

<h:panelGroup> <!--rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"-->
    <h:panelGroup  id="errorDisplay"><!--rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"-->
        <span>发生以下错误：</span>
        <ol style="color:red;">
            <ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList}" var="m">
                <li>${m.detail}</li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ol>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```